# Tensoflow: Input 0 of layer "conv1d_17" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 16)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

Although I could find similar questions, I have not been able to fix this issue.

I am trying to classify text, but got this error:

Input 0 of layer "conv1d_17" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 16)

> Blockquote
> # Training a Text Classification Model using a Convolutional Layer

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("Financeiro_Teste_V3.csv")

df.head(3)

df.info()

df = df.dropna()

X = df.loc[:, "HISTÓRICO"]
X

y = df.loc[:, ['PROCESSO']]
y.head(7)

training_sentences, testing_sentences, training_labels, testing_labels = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, train_size = .75)

training_sentences = training_sentences.to_numpy()

testing_sentences = testing_sentences.to_numpy() 

# testing_sentences

#for x in testing_sentences:
#  print(type(x), x)

## Data preprocessing

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

vocab_size = 10000
max_length = 120
trunc_type='post'
padding_type='post'
oov_tok = "<OOV>"

# Initialize the Tokenizer class
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)

# Generate the word index dictionary
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

# Generate and pad the training sequences
training_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_sentences)
training_padded = pad_sequences(training_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)

# Generate and pad the testing sequences
testing_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(testing_sentences)
testing_padded = pad_sequences(testing_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)

# Convert the labels lists into numpy arrays
training_labels = np.array(training_labels)
testing_labels = np.array(testing_labels)

## Build and Compile the Model

import tensorflow as tf

# Parameters
embedding_dim = 16
filters = 128
kernel_size = 1
dense_dim = 6

# Model Definition with Conv1D
model_conv = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax')
])

# Set the training parameters
    model_conv.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    # Print the model summary
    model_conv.summary()
    
    ## Train the Model
    
    NUM_EPOCHS = 20
    
    # Train the model
    history_conv = model_conv.fit(training_padded, training_labels, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, validation_data=(testing_padded, testing_labels))
    
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    # Plot Utility
    def plot_graphs(history, string):
      plt.plot(history.history[string])
      plt.plot(history.history['val_'+string])
      plt.xlabel("Epochs")
      plt.ylabel(string)
      plt.legend([string, 'val_'+string])
      plt.show()
    
    # Plot the accuracy and loss history
    plot_graphs(history_conv, 'accuracy')
    plot_graphs(history_conv, 'loss')
    
    model_conv.predict(testing_sentences)
      
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 120) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 120), dtype=tf.float32, name='embedding_3_input'), name='embedding_3_input', description="created by layer 'embedding_3_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-98046d2f0914> in <module>
----> 1 model_conv.predict(testing_sentences)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1801, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1783, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 228, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_3" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "conv1d_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 16)
```

Comment: only change here; model_conv.predict(["testing_sentences"]) you have defined as string and not a variable and even notice it must have been padded sequence after converted texts into sequence

Comment: hi @SoroushMirzaei, thanks for you reply. I had tried both ways, as a string and as an ndarray and got the same error message. I have updated the question

Comment: no, you didnt notice what i said, as the model trains on the padded sequences (var training_padded) you should fed your desired data into model with the same structure, in this case, first put sentence in the list and then convert into sequences by tokenizer.texts_to_sequences() and then pad_sqeunces as the same operations that you have done for preprocessing training and validation set, the model requires even the same operation for each sentence you want to use model.predict()

Comment: even notice to reshape or expand dimension of the inputs for model prediction, as you know the inputs must have been 2D for prediction and training.

Comment: SOLVED: Hi, @SoroushMirzaei Thank you again. Yeah, you were right. I have just followed your instruction: 1. Converted the text to numpy array 2. Converted texts_to_sequences then padded. Now they are in the same shape and working perfectly. Thanks a lot